Refetch data using useAsyncData in nuxt 3 on lang change
Hey I have multilingual page in nuxt 3 and I use prismic.io as an CMS. I have problem with navbar. When I change the language, the link translations change, but not the number of links. For example, I have two links in the English version and three in the Chinese version when I initially fetch data from English version, it won’t show on Chinese one. I use useAsyncData to retrieve data from prismic. I don't know how to use something to watch language and refetch data after that. Doese anyone know how to help me. I share code to undestand more what I mean.
const { locale } = useI18n()
const { lang } = getPageLang(locale.value)
const { data: navi } = await useAsyncData(`${PAGE_NAME.NAVI_NAVBAR}_${lang}`, () =>
  client.getByUID(PAGE_TYPE.NAVI, PAGE_NAME.NAVI_NAVBAR, { lang })
)

